# Having dealt vs dealing with

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's put Captain America's morality sturuggle as an example:

> ''After **having dealt** severe internal battles conflicting with his sense of morality, Steve Rogers has shed his Captain America persona altogether''*(a new man in infinity war-the avengers)*

To

> "After **dealing with his** severe internal battles conflicting with his sense of morality, Steve Rogers has shed his Captain America persona altogether''*(a new man in infinity war-the avengers)*

Are the bold letters similar to each other?

Comment: Do you mean "After having dealt *with his* severe internal battles... "  Did you mean to omit the words "with his" from the first quote?

Comment: The first sentence is an excerpt, absolutely no omission, whereas, the second one is my constructed phrase to see if I undertand(the first sentence) fully using my own words.

Comment: Can you cite the source of the excerpt please.

Comment: I would just say the first example is incorrect (wrongly transcribed by OP, not properly proofread, whatever - as pointed out, the word ***with*** appears to be missing).

Comment: I get it now, thx. In case you still want to check the source of that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX4MzOFTB5U (Captain America section @2:21) feel free to look into this link